# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am starting to learn how to implement neural networks with keras. However, I just now stumbled across this error. I don't know what I did wrong here. I am working alongside the youtube tutorials of Valerio: [His vids on implementing an autoencoder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtyoFTyJuEY).

My code:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, LSTM

class GNN:
  """
  GNN is a graph neural network.
  """
  
  def __init__(self, 
               input_shape_emb,
               input_shape_lstm
              ):
    
    
    
    self.input_shape_emb = input_shape_emb # [1, 38]
    self.input_shape_lstm = input_shape_lstm # [1,348]
    self.embedding_shape = 92
    
    
    self.emb = None
    self.lstm = None
    self.mpls = None
    self.model = None
    
    self._num_lstm_cells = 4
    
    self._build()
    
    
  def summary(self):
    self.emb.summary()
    self.lstm.summary()
    
  def _build(self):
    self._build_emb
    self._build_lstm
    #self._build_mlps
    
    
    
  def _build_emb(self):
    embedding_input = self._add_embedding_input()
    embedding_output = self._add_dense_layer(embedding_input)
    self.emb = tensorflow.keras.Model(embedding_input, embedding_output, name="embedding")
  
  def _add_embedding_input(self):
    return Input(shape=self.input_shape_emb, name="embedding_input")
  
  def _add_dense_layer(self,embedding_input):
    num_neurons = self.embedding_shape
    return Dense(num_neurons, name="embedding_dense")(embedding_input)
  
  
  
  
  def _build_lstm(self):
    lstm_input = self._add_lstm_input()
    lstm_layers = self._add_lstm_cells(lstm_input)
    self.lstm = tensorflow.keras.Model(lstm_input, lstm_layers, name="lstm_network")
  
  def _add_lstm_input(self):
    return Input(shape=self.input_shape_lstm, name="lstm_network_input")

  def _add_lstm_cells(self, lstm_input):
    """Creates all lstm cell blocks in lstm network."""
    x = lstm_input
    for cell_index in range(self._num_lstm_cells):
      x = self._add_lstm_cell(cell_index, x)
    return x
  
  def _add_lstm_cell(self, cell_index, x):
    """Adds an lstm cell to a graph of cells, consisting of
    lstm + ReLu + Dropout.
    """
    lstm_cell = LSTM(
      256, activation='relu', dropout=0.1, name = f"lstm_cell_{cell_index+1}"
    )
    x = lstm_cell(x)
    return x
    
    
    
    
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  model = GNN(
    input_shape_emb = (1051, 38), #Input_DFS_sequence[0].shape, #(1051, 38)
    input_shape_lstm = 348
  )
  model.summary()
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-xx> in <module>
     92     input_shape_lstm = 348
     93   )
---> 94   model.summary()
     95 
     96 

<command-xx> in summary(self)
     32 
     33   def summary(self):
---> 34     self.emb.summary()
     35     self.lstm.summary()
     36 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `self._build_emb` and `self._build_lstm` are not being called.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, you're asking the wrong question. It should be "why do I have `None` there when I expect something else?". That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `emb` to `None` after calling `_build()` which actually assigns the variable; this is true of other attributes, too. Instead default it to `None` first.

```
self.emb = None
self.lstm = None
self.mpls = None
self.model = None
self._build()
```

You're also not calling the functions to actually build the attributes inside `_build()`.

```
def _build(self):
    self._build_emb()
    self._build_lstm()
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I put the `self._build()` after the `None` definitions, I still get the error. I had it before like this, but forgot to switch it back. The updated code is given above.

Comment: @Omatikaya see my edit

Comment: Oh wow, of course they are also functions! Thank you!